# Browserify on PhantomJS script with `require('webpage')`

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, browserify

How can I run browserify on a JavaScript module that requires the PhantomJS `webpage` module?

Since the `webpage` module is provided by PhantomJS, browserify can't find it and I get `Error: module "webpage" not found`. The `--ignore` and `--exclude` options both produce the error. The `--ignore-missing` option eliminates the import altogether.

Does browserify have a way to indicate that certain uses of `require` should not be included as a bundle dependency?

### Background

I'm trying to write a PhantomJS script in ES6. I can transpile a single script into ES5 code that runs in PhantomJS, and I'm trying to use Browserify to transpile the entire dependency tree. Unfortunately, there are some dependencies it shouldn't pull in—those provided by PhantomJS—and compilation breaks because it can find those modules.

Perhaps I should be using a different tool than Browserify?

Comment: PhantomJS has an execution environment distinct from node.js, so you can't use browserify on PhantomJS scripts. PhantomJS is a full browser that cannot be browserified. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have a script I want to run with PhantomJS, but I want to break it into modules and join it back together into one script with Browserify. Unfortunately, I have no way to tell Browserify which imports it should try to read and which are provided by PhantomJS.

Comment: I meant what do you want to achieve in the grand scheme of thing. Do you want to run a PhantomJS script directly in the client browser? => not possible.

Comment: I want to run a PhantomJS script in PhantomJS.

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you need browserify in that case? Can you provide a minimal code example?

Comment: I've added some description of the big picture.

Answer (score -1):

```
// browserify will resolve someNodeModule and include it in the bundle
var mymodule = require('someNodeModule');

var _require = require;
// browserify will ignore this, so 'webpage' is resolved at runtime inside phantomjs
var webpage = _require('webpage');
```

Comment: Could you modify your answer to explain how your code is solving the problem?